# Ошибка при рестарте приложения BadParcelableException

Tags: java, android, классы, android-bundle

Добрый день!

По поводу данной ошибки много тем открыто, однако однозначного решения не нашел. После того, как пользователь перестает работать с приложением (5-10 часов), при открытии программа крашится. Если сразу же открыть приложение повторно, то всё работает без проблем.

Вот лог:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vonegosh.creditcalc/com.vonegosh.creditcalc.ActivityInputParams}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2484)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2544)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1394)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:168)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5845)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:797)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:687)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:
android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2420)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2346)
com.vonegosh.creditcalc.Calc.<init> (Calc.java:31)
com.vonegosh.creditcalc.Calc$1.createFromParcel (Calc.java:39)
com.vonegosh.creditcalc.Calc$1.createFromParcel (Calc.java:36)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2355)
android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2252)
android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:2601)
android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:221)
android.os.Bundle.getParcelable (Bundle.java:786)
com.vonegosh.creditcalc.FragmentView2.onCreateView (FragmentView2.java:56)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:1974)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1067)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1252)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1234)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:2046)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:174)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:597)
com.vonegosh.creditcalc.ActivityInputParams.onStart (ActivityInputParams.java:607)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1288)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6264)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2447)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2544)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1394)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:168)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5845)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:797)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Класс

```
public class Calc implements Parcelable {


    // Double global_platej = 0.0;
    ArrayList<Payment> payment_list;
    Context context;
    DB db;
    SharPref sharPref;
    LoanParametr lp_origin, lp;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    private boolean isWithDopPayment = true;


    protected Calc(Parcel in) {
        payment_list = in.createTypedArrayList(Payment.CREATOR);
        lp_origin = in.readParcelable(LoanParametr.class.getClassLoader());
        lp = in.readParcelable(LoanParametr.class.getClassLoader());
        isWithDopPayment = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Calc> CREATOR = new Creator<Calc>() {
        @Override
        public Calc createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Calc(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Calc[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Calc[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(lp, 0);
        dest.writeParcelable(lp_origin, 1);
        dest.writeArray(payment_list.toArray());
        dest.writeBooleanArray(new boolean[]{isWithDopPayment});
    }
                 ////////////////////////много лишнего кода
}
```

Как я понимаю, система не может восстановить экземпляр класса Calc в методе 
 protected Calc(Parcel in), однако причина мне не ясна.

**UPD:** В общем, ошибка повторилась, однако я лучше подготовился. 
Мне нужно было найти способ повторять ошибку вручную, потому что оставлять телефон на день в надежде, что система убьет приложение было нецелесообразно. В итоге зашел в пункт меню "Для разработчиков" - "Расширенные" - "Лимит фоновых процессов" и установил значение "Без фоновых процессов". Теперь заходим в основное приложение, сворачиваем, заходим в другое рандомное приложение, система убивает основное приложение, пытаемся зайти обратно, система пытается восстановить объекты, но не выходит и приложение крашится.

Теперь про логику программы. Расположил экземпляры классов в правильном порядке, хотя порядок сгенерировал Android Studio.

```
 protected Calc(Parcel in) {
     lp = in.readParcelable(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
     lp_origin = in.readParcelable(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
     payment_list = in.createTypedArrayList(Payment.CREATOR);
     isWithDopPayment = in.readByte() != 0;
   }

    public static final Creator<Calc> CREATOR = new Creator<Calc>() {
        @Override
        public Calc createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Calc(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Calc[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Calc[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(lp, 0);
        dest.writeParcelable(lp_origin, 1);
        dest.writeList(payment_list);
        dest.writeBooleanArray(new boolean[]{isWithDopPayment});
    }
```

**lp_origin** - экземпляр класса, который заполняется значениями заранее и передается в конструктор Calc.

```
public Calc(DB db, LoanParametr lp, Context context) {
        this.lp_origin = lp;
        this.db = db;
        this.context = context;
        sharPref = new SharPref(context);
    }
```

**lp** - экземпляр класса, который объявляется в классе Calc как копия 
**lp_origin**, после чего с ним проводятся операции.

```
public void FormDataArray() {
        //////много кода
        lp = new LoanParametr(lp_origin);
        //////много кода
}
```

Вот, собственно, конструктор для создания копии

```
LoanParametr(LoanParametr lp) {
        this.NameTable = lp.getNameTable();
        this.NameCredit = lp.getNameCredit();
        this.summ = lp.getSumm();
        this.DateOfIssue = lp.getDateOfIssue();
        this.DateOfTheFirstPayment = lp.getDateOfTheFirstPayment();
        this.term = lp.getTerm();
        this.percent = lp.getPercent();
        this.typeOfPayment = lp.getTypeOfPayment();
        this.firstPayment = lp.firstPayment;
        this.firstInterestOnly = lp.getFirstInterestOnly();
        this.weekend = lp.getWeekend();
        this.lastDayMonth = lp.getLastDayMonth();
        this.EDcom = lp.getEDcom();
        this.Ezhcom = lp.getEzhcom();
        this.simpleInterest = lp.getSimpleInterest();
        this.raiffeisen = lp.getRaiffeisen();
    }
```

**payment_list** - ArrayList класса Payment

```
public class Payment implements Parcelable {

    private int number = 0;
    private long date_payment = 0L;
    private double platej = 0.0;
    private double dept = 0.0;
    private double percent = 0.0;
    private double remain_dept = 0.0;
    private double um_summ = 0.0;
    private double um_term = 0.0;
    private double izm_percent = 0.0;
    private double com = 0.0;
    private double insuranse = 0.0;
    private int type_plateja = 0;
    private int baks = 0;
    private int todebt = 0;
    private double izm_payment = 0;

    public double getIzm_payment() {
        return izm_payment;
    }

    public void setIzm_payment(int izm_payment) {
        this.izm_payment = izm_payment;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public Payment() {
    }

    public Integer getType_plateja() {
        return type_plateja;
    }

    public void setType_plateja(Integer type_plateja) {
        this.type_plateja = type_plateja;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Long getDate_payment() {
        return date_payment;
    }


    public void setDate_payment(Long date_payment) {
        this.date_payment = date_payment;
    }

    public Double getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }

    public void setPercent(Double percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    public Double getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(Double dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public Double getPlatej() {
        return platej;
    }

    public void setPlatej(Double platej) {
        this.platej = platej;
    }

    public Double getRemain_dept() {

        return remain_dept;
    }

    public void setRemain_dept(Double remain_dept) {
        this.remain_dept = remain_dept;
    }

    public Double getUm_summ() {
        return um_summ;
    }

    public void setUm_summ(Double um_summ) {
        this.um_summ = um_summ;
    }

    public Double getUm_term() {
        return um_term;
    }

    public void setUm_term(Double um_term) {
        this.um_term = um_term;
    }

    public Double getIzm_percent() {
        return izm_percent;
    }

    public void setIzm_percent(Double izm_percent) {
        this.izm_percent = izm_percent;
    }

    public Double getCom() {
        return com;
    }

    public void setCom(Double com) {
        this.com = com;
    }

    public Double getInsuranse() {
        return insuranse;
    }

    public void setInsuranse(Double insuranse) {
        this.insuranse = insuranse;
    }

    public Integer getBaks() {
        return baks;
    }

    public void setBaks(Integer baks) {
        this.baks = baks;
    }

    public Integer getTodebt() {
        return todebt;
    }

    public void setTodebt(Integer todebt) {
        this.todebt = todebt;
    }

    public Payment(Integer number,
                   Long date_payment,
                   Double platej,
                   Double dept,
                   Double percent,
                   Double remain_dept,
                   Double um_summ,
                   Double um_term,
                   Double izm_percent,
                   Double com,
                   Double insuranse,
                   Integer type_plateja,
                   Integer baks,
                   Integer todebt,
                   Double izm_payment
    ) {
        this.number = number;
        this.date_payment = date_payment;
        this.platej = platej;
        this.dept = dept;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.remain_dept = remain_dept;
        this.um_summ = um_summ;
        this.um_term = um_term;
        this.izm_percent = izm_percent;
        this.com = com;
        this.insuranse = insuranse;
        this.type_plateja = type_plateja;
        this.baks = baks;
        this.todebt = todebt;
        this.izm_payment = izm_payment;

    }

    Payment(Parcel parcel) {

        this.number = parcel.readInt();
        this.date_payment = parcel.readLong();
        this.platej = parcel.readDouble();
        this.dept = parcel.readDouble();
        this.percent = parcel.readDouble();
        this.remain_dept = parcel.readDouble();
        this.um_summ = parcel.readDouble();
        this.um_term = parcel.readDouble();
        this.izm_percent = parcel.readDouble();
        this.com = parcel.readDouble();
        this.insuranse = parcel.readDouble();
        this.type_plateja = parcel.readInt();
        this.baks = parcel.readInt();
        this.todebt = parcel.readInt();
        this.izm_payment = parcel.readDouble();

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
                   parcel.writeInt(number);
            parcel.writeLong(date_payment);
            parcel.writeDouble(platej);
            parcel.writeDouble(dept);
            parcel.writeDouble(percent);
            parcel.writeDouble(remain_dept);
            parcel.writeDouble(um_summ);
            parcel.writeDouble(um_term);
            parcel.writeDouble(izm_percent);
            parcel.writeDouble(com);
            parcel.writeDouble(insuranse);
            parcel.writeInt(type_plateja);
            parcel.writeInt(baks);
            parcel.writeInt(todebt);
            parcel.writeDouble(izm_payment);
        }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Payment> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Payment>() {
        @Override
        public Payment createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Payment(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Payment[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Payment[size];
        }
    };
}
```

В конечном итоге что получается ( знак "==" означает - возвращается при попытке восстановления данных системой)

**lp** == **origin**

**lp_origin** == ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling

**payment_list** == пустой Arraylist

Кто-нибудь разъясните, пожалуйста, как происходит процедура восстановления данных? Как тут задействует ClassLoader и, по возможности, как устранить проблему?

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
```

Что из себя представляет переменная flags?

Comment: Записывать и считывать значения нужно **обязательно** в одинаковом порядке. У вас же порядок разный

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка не повторяется!

Comment: Написал в ответ)

Comment: Попробуйте флаги передавать ри записи не 0 и 1, а те, что в аргумент пришли.  При чтении испоьзуйте класс-лоадер класса, коий пишите - т.е. не `this`, а так как раньше было - `LoanParametr.class.getClassLoader()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Сделал, не помогло. Я даже попробовал запаковать два экзепляра класса **lp** и **lp_origin**  в **ArrayList<LoanParametr>** и записать их через **writeTypedList**, но в итоге всеми способами возвращается только 1ый экземпляр, который я записал в первую очередь, а второй null.

Comment: Хм... Ну... А что, если их не подряд записывать, а поствить меж ними запись/чтение чего-нить другого??

Comment: Благодарю, проблема была в классе LoanParametr. Там последовательность чтения / записи была нарушена. По Вашему совету исправил и ошибка пропала

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записывать и считывать значения нужно обязательно в одинаковом порядке. У вас же порядок разный.

Так что просто поменяйте порядок записи/чтения на идентичный.